# UIView Animation Move

Tags: ios, animation, uiview

I have managed to make the "view" move once. I need for it to stay `1 second` in same place and then move back again to initial place. How would I add the rest of the code for this? **(This won't be a loop, only done once)**

```
[UIView animateWithDuration:0.8 delay:0 options:UIViewAnimationOptionCurveEaseInOut animations:^{
        [infoView setCenter:CGPointMake(160,30)];
    } completion:nil];
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the completion block to do another animation:

```
[UIView animateWithDuration:0.8 delay:0 options:UIViewAnimationOptionCurveEaseInOut animations:^{
    [infoView setCenter:CGPointMake(160,30)];
} completion:^(BOOL finished) {
    [UIView animateWithDuration:0.8 delay:1 options:UIViewAnimationOptionCurveEaseInOut animations:^{
        [infoView setCenter:CGPointMake(orignalX, originalY)];
    } completion:nil];
}];
```

Comment: I get an error: Incompatible block pointer types sending 'void(^)(void)'to parameter of type 'void (^)(BOOL)'

Comment: Fixed - I had a typo.